# PHP Preg_replace after a specific amount of characters with a conditional

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been working on this for a bit, but my regex is weak.

I need to check to see if a number is a whole number (single digit) and append a ".001" to it if so. The problem is, it's in the middle of a line with values separated by commas.

MATERIALS,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,**1**,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1

**Needs to be**

MATERIALS,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,**1.001**,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1

1. The line must start with "MATERIALS".
2. There are more than one MATERIALS lines.
3. The value will always be after 5 commas.

I was trying something like this to even replace the number, but I don't think the approach is quite right:

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/(MATERIALS)(,.*?){4}(,\d+?),/', '\2,', $stripped);
```

I tried going through a preg_match_all > for > if process, to at least get the conditional working, but I still have to replace the lines.

EDIT: I forgot the `preg_match_all` line that proceeded the loop.

```
preg_match_all('/MATERIALS.*/', $stripped, $materialsLines);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($materialsLines[0]);$i++) {
            $section = explode(",",$materialsLines[0][$i]);
            if (strlen($section[5]) == 1) {
                $section[5] .= ".001";
            }
            $materialsLines[0][$i] = implode(",",$section);
        }
```

Comment: is this text always separated by newlines? You could perform a preg_match for "MATERIALS", grab it's line, implode it into an array using comma as the delimiter, and then run a check to see if the number is a float or an integer on the 5th array element (array[4]) and set the value if it's a whole number.

Comment: That's what I started to do with my second approach, but preg_match doesn't help with replace and then I'm still left trying to make preg_replace work.

Comment: preg_replace might not be the best option here. If all you need to do is simply add .001 to a whole number, you would append the array variable like so: if(ctype_digit($array[4])) $array[4].=".001";

Comment: Isn't the content stored in the preg_match_all array just a copy of the content? Appending to that string won't change the line in the context of the rest of the content, right?

Comment: That was implying you imploded the line into an array. I will provide an example answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a regex? You can simply explode the string on comma, check the value in [5], fix it and join the string back together.

```
$str = 'MATERIALS,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,1,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1';
$line = explode(',',$str);
if(strpos($line[5],'.')===false){
    $line[5] .= '.001';
}
$str = implode(',', $line);
```

http://codepad.org/g4r3pLpS

If reading multiple lines from a file:

```
$file = file("someFile.txt");
foreach($file as $key=>$line){
    $line = explode(',', $line);
    if($line[0] == 'MATERIALS'){
        if(strpos($line[5],'.')!==false){
            $line[5] .= '.001';
            $file[$key] = implode(',', $line);
        }
    }
}
file_put_contents("someFile2.txt", implode('',$file));
```

if for some reason you HAVE to use a regex, this worked for me:

```
$str = 'MATERIALS,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,1,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1
MATERIALS,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,1.101,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1
FOO,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,1.1,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1
BLAH,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,1,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1
MATERIALS,1,1,9999;1 4PL1 PB_Mel,,567,6,0.173,0.173,0.375,0,0.375,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,1';

$str = preg_replace('/^(MATERIALS(,[^,]*){4},)(\d+),/m', '$1$3.001,', $str);
echo $str;
```

http://codepad.org/l7FfJlDe

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(MATERIALS,(?:[^,]*,){4}\d+)(?=,)/m', "$1.001", $str);
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/je7Gbi)**.

Answer (score 0):

this could work: (but idk whole structure of your string)

```
$pattern = '#(MATERIALS,[0-9]{1},[0-9]{1},[0-9]{4};[^,]*,,[^,]),#';
$replacement = '${1}.001,'; // where ${1} references to pattern matches
$string = 'your string'
$matches  = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```